# Combining sibling DNA data for easier research

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna

I have DNA from four of my siblings (they were tested at three different places).  I'd like to find a way of easily combining our raw DNA data into two files -- even if the files weren't sorted by our two parents (visual phasing I've found is too complex and not totally accurate anyway). The main objective for doing this is, to find all the matches (of 5 DNA donors) without having to compare all the matches to each other. (Ideally, I'd like to make one big file, but I know, theoretically, that this isn't possible.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are aiming for – you can't just combine raw data from multiple people because you will end up with four or more nucleotides at each SNP, which ultimately would mean there would be a huge number of random false positive matches.

Comment: I don't have much understanding about the biology of DNA...  but then how does the Lazarus tool on GEDmatch reconstruct an ancestor kit from numerous related descendants?  (I have to review this tool to see why I wasn't able to use it for doing what I have requested above.)